# Unity Photon | How Can I Delete a Room When the Owner Leaves?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am making an online game project for the first time and I have made systems such as leaving the room, setting up a room, but when I click the "delete room" button, I want to delete the room and kick everyone in it. How can I do that?

i tried `PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.isOpen = false and PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.isVisible = false` didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `PhotonNetwork.CloseConnection(PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer);` But for this to work you also need to set `EnableCloseConnection = true` before that.

Also even though it is not related with your question, i would strongly advise to use photon fusion if you are just started on your project. It is harder to use but bigger changes are no longer planned for PUN 2 anymore and fusion is recommended for all recent and new projects.

Comment: I had already set EnableCloseConnection to true before running it.

Comment: I also tried to take all the players from the playerList one by one and kick them with the for loop. Sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't.

Comment: When creating the room you need to pass in Room options. One of them is to close a room as soon as the last player left. You will need to actively "kick" all players .. otherwise the "ownership" is simply transfered to another client.. and as there is no real way to kick players you basically need to send a certain time message to everyone to please leave the room - in code of course ;)